# Upgrade Ubuntu from 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS will erase my personal files?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

Sorry for that beginner Q.
If I upgrade my  Ubuntu from 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04.1 LTS it will erase my personal files and installed software?

something else, I see there some problems with others after upgrading, it is right to upgrade now?
what are the criteria that I decide to upgrade based on?

Thank You,,

Comment: No, it wont erase personal files. But having a backup is necessary anyway if you have important data.

Comment: In my opinion, most upgrade problems occur because people add 3rd party software to their systems. The more 3rd party software added, the greater the risk of problems. To ensure a ~clean upgrade, you could remove all 3rd party software, upgrade, reboot then add it back (if needed), but my *fall-back* is usually to re-install if problems become a hassle (*I don't expect problems anyway as I consider everything I add to my system to begin with*). FYI: the install I'm talking about is *something else*, selecting existing partitions ensure you don't format you partitions. It won't erase user data

Comment: Having backups are important.  An upgrade or install is quite major to the system and not always perfect.  An upgrade will try to keep all your data, but might use different software.